# My Collatz conjecture code is in an infinite loop. Any number I enter never changes when the program executes. Thoughts?

Tags: python

```py
def is_even(number):
    return number % 2 == 0


def check_number(number):
    if is_even(number):
        number = number // 2
    else:
        number = 3 * number + 1



def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        print(number)
        check_number(number)
    print("Final number is: " + str(number))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    collatz(number)
```

Comment: `number` only changes locally in `check_number` but in `collatz` it will remain the same

Comment: Reassigning `number` inside `check_number` does not affect any variables outside `check_number`. That is not how variables work.

Comment: You should return new value from `check_number` and assign it back to `number` inside you're loop

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses!! I added "number = check_number(number)" in my loop and it works great!! I had been looking at this for several hours and didn't see the issue. Thanks again!!

def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        print(number)
        check_number(number)
        number = check_number(number)
    print("Final number is: " + str(number))

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - how do I paste my code to look readable? It wraps when I paste it and you were able to make it look correctly formatted. Thanks!!

Comment: Here is about [code formatting on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)